# php/mysql time data retrieval and creating a countdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've been working on a flash game which will be on a website and will be played by all users at the same time and I am stuck at the following issue.

A round in that game lasts an amount of time, let's say 1 minute. Then they have to wait 30 seconds for the next round to start. But the thing i don't know how to script (i'm working with php and javascript), is that if someone enters the game in the middle of the round, i want to make them wait until the end of the round and display some sort of countdown, or give them to possibility of joining the game at that moment (joining the game means loading the .swf file or redirecting them to the respective page).

More specifically, how can i get the remaining time of the round and create a countdown from that time, no matter when you enter the page? Maybe store the remaining time in a database and retrieve it, but isn't the execution time of the script going to interfere with the time stored in the database. I'm confused.

Also, is this hard to script so that it would be secure?

If you could give me some ideas i would be so glad, because i don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: How much money would you like to spend?

Comment: You could use Ajax on the HTML page to fetch the current game's start time (on page load) and then refresh the countdown with javascript on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I depends on how you structure your data of course, one of the ways to go is to fetch start time of the round and then do the math client side showing a countdown time with client script.

In terms of security, you should implement an authoritative server structure, in which server is the man that determines, for example, how hard a player can hit and if he is allowed to do so and a client only transmits an intent to do so.

For the touchy moments of securing your app, like when you need to authenticate a user, you can always look into RSA encryption.

P.S.
If you allow me to through in an opinionated remark... please ignore if it offends someone. I do not think that PHP + JavaScript is such a hot combination. If what your server does is serves a flash file inside a html page and then responds to api calls the better way would be to use node.js for game logic API and ruby on rails for serving web front-end (although node can be used for that as well)

Comment: I managed to do it with Ajax. Thanks for giving me a boost in the right direction. And also thanks for your opinion on combining PHP and JavaScript. Since this isn't such a complicated project, it works fine, but i will look into node.js and ruby on rails in the immediate future. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome, I'd be very grateful if you thumb it up in case you liked it ty